# Как выбрать определенное значение <select> нажатием на кнопку?

Tags: javascript

На сайте есть фильтр. В нем есть параметры, которые находятся внутри тега `<select>`.
Есть рядом боковое меню, внутри него несколько `<button>` со своими текстовым значением.
Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, текст внутри неё сравнивался со значениями `<select>` и тот, который совпадал, становился выбранным (selected).

```css
.button-value {
  display: block;
}
.select-filter {
 margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<select class="select-filter">
   <option>Значение 1</option>
   <option>Значение 2</option>
   <option>Значение 3</option>
</select>

<button class="button-value">Значение 1</button>
<button class="button-value">Значение 2</button>
<button class="button-value">Значение 3</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { // При загрузке документа
        let sel = document.querySelector('.select-filter'); // Получаем селект
        let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button-value'); // Получаем кнопки с классом
        buttons.forEach(function (c) { // Для каждой кнопки
            c.onclick = function () { // Слушаем нажатие
                sel.value = c.innerText; // Если нажата, то выбирает тот option, который в тексте кнопки.
            }
        })
    })
```

```css
    .button-value {
        display: block;
    }
    .select-filter {
        margin-bottom: 40px;
    }
```

```html
<select class="select-filter">
    <option>Значение 1</option>
    <option>Значение 2</option>
    <option>Значение 3</option>
</select>

<button class="button-value">Значение 1</button>
<button class="button-value">Значение 2</button>
<button class="button-value">Значение 3</button>
```

Comment: Подскажите, не выходит ни первый, ни второй Ваш скрипт на сайте, ошибка-конфликт была связана с другим, когда решил, теперь вообще ничего не происходит. Вы не против, если я скину ссылку на сайт?

Comment: @QuickBrownFox Добрый день. Да, давайте.

Comment: Добрый день, https://мои-квадраты.рф. Кнопка находится в боковом сайдбаре, аккордеон "ЖК по расположению". При нажатии на button, должен выбираться "Карасунский" в фильтре по центру. Он становится пустым, а в консоли ничего не происходит.

Comment: @QuickBrownFox Подскажите, как можно воспроизвести ошибку?

Comment: Обновил предыдущий комментарий

Comment: @QuickBrownFox Из-за ошики `Maximumcall stack size exceeded.` У Вас происходит перывание выполнения скрипта.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, из за чего может быть подобная штука? Все вроде бы работает, только с этим подобная проблема

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106463/discussion-between-quick-brown-fox-and-denis640kb).

Answer (score 0):

Постановка вопроса не совсем верная. Нужно просто задать `select.value` это и будет по сути изменение значения `selected`. Если надо, чтобы сгенерировалось событие `change` для `select` нужно сделать это явно:

```js
let select = document.querySelector('.select-filter');
document.querySelectorAll('.button-value').forEach(b => {
    b.addEventListener('click', e => {
         select.value = e.target.textContent;
         select.dispatchEvent(new Event('change')); // Вызываем событие change
    });
})

select.onchange = () => {
    console.log('changed', select.value);
}
```

```css
.button-value {
  display: block;
}
.select-filter {
 margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<select class="select-filter">
   <option>Значение 1</option>
   <option>Значение 2</option>
   <option>Значение 3</option>
</select>

<button class="button-value">Значение 1</button>
<button class="button-value">Значение 2</button>
<button class="button-value">Значение 3</button>
```